# InvalidCastException Casting Dictionary Values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to load a list of values from a Dictionary. I can iterate through the list and
get the values, but get an InvalidCastException

> ```
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 
>   'WhereListIterator`1[PumpTubing.Tubing]' to type 'PumpTubing.Tubing'.
> ```

when trying to use the following:

```
Dim tb2 As List(Of Tubing) = pd.pumps.Values.
                                Select(Function(f) f.
                                Where(Function(t) t.Tube.Equals("Tube3"))).
                                Cast(Of Tubing)().ToList()
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried several variations and cannot get it to work.

I've included a method to Load some test data.

Following is my code:

```
Module Module1

Private pd As New PumpData

Sub Main()

    LoadTestData()

    ' This works and returns a a List with 3 entries
    Dim tb1 As New List(Of Tubing)
    For Each x As KeyValuePair(Of Pumps, List(Of Tubing)) In pd.pumps
        For Each t As Tubing In x.Value
            If t.Tube.Equals("Tube3") Then tb1.Add(t)
        Next
    Next

    ' The following throws an InvalidCastExcption:
    '
    ' Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 
    ' 'WhereListIterator`1[PumpTubing.Tubing]' to type 'PumpTubing.Tubing'.
    Dim tb2 As List(Of Tubing) = pd.pumps.Values.
                                    Select(Function(f) f.
                                    Where(Function(t) t.Tube.Equals("Tube3"))).
                                    Cast(Of Tubing)().ToList()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadTestData()

    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump1", .MaxFlowRate = 300},
                                New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube1", .VPR = 1.1},
                                                          New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube2", .VPR = 1.2}})
    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump2", .MaxFlowRate = 400},
                        New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube3", .VPR = 1.3},
                                                  New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube4", .VPR = 1.4}})
    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump3", .MaxFlowRate = 500},
                        New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube5", .VPR = 1.1},
                                                  New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube6", .VPR = 1.2}})
    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump4", .MaxFlowRate = 600},
                        New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube3", .VPR = 1.33},
                                                  New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube7", .VPR = 1.4}})
    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump5", .MaxFlowRate = 700},
                        New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube1", .VPR = 1.15},
                                                  New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube8", .VPR = 1.2}})
    pd.pumps.Add(New Pumps With {.Model = "Pump6", .MaxFlowRate = 800},
                        New List(Of Tubing) From {New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube3", .VPR = 1.35},
                                                  New Tubing With {.Tube = "Tube9", .VPR = 1.4}})

End Sub

End Module
```

Here are the classes:

```
Public Class Pumps
    Property Model As String
    Property MaxFlowRate As Integer
End Class

Public Class Tubing
    Property Tube As String
    Property VPR As Decimal
End Class

Public Class PumpData
    Property pumps As New Dictionary(Of Pumps, List(Of Tubing))
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so good at VB syntax (coming from c#), but I guess you meant to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`:

```
Dim tb2 As List(Of Tubing) = pd.pumps.Values.
                            SelectMany(Function(f) f.
                            Where(Function(t) t.Tube.Equals("Tube3"))).
                            Cast(Of Tubing)().ToList()
```

Comment: That was it.  Thx.